# Manual allocation in a stringbuffer object

Tags: c, memory, embedded, malloc, calloc

For a small to-be-embedded application, I wrote a few functions + struct that work as String Buffer (similar to std::stringstream in C++).

While the code as such works fine, There are a few not-so-minor problems:

- I never before wrote functions in C that manually allocate *and* use growing memory, thus I'm afraid there are still some quirks that yet need to be adressed
- It seems the code allocates far more memory than it actually needs, which is ***VERY BAD***
- Due to warnings reported by valgrind I have switched from `malloc` to `calloc` in one place in the code, which sucessfully removed the warning, but I'm not entirely sure if i'm actually using it correctly

Example of what I mean that it allocates more than it really needs (using a 56k file):

```
==23668== HEAP SUMMARY:
==23668==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==23668==   total heap usage: 49,998 allocs, 49,998 frees, 1,249,875,362 bytes allocated
```

... It just doesn't look right ...

The code in question is here (too large to copy it in a `<code>` field on SO): http://codepad.org/LQzphUzd

Help is needed, and I'm grateful for any advice!

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you are growing your buffer is rather inefficient. For each little piece of string, you realloc() memory, which can mean new memory is allocated and the contents of the "old" memory are copied over. That is slow and fragments your heap.

Better is to grow in fixed amounts, or in fixed percentages, i.e. make the new size 1.5 or 2 times the size of the old size. That also wastes some memory, but will keep the heap more usable and not so many copies are made.

This means you'll have to keep track of two values: capacity (number of bytes allocated) and length (actual length of the string). But that should not be too hard.

I would introduce a function "FstrBuf_Grow" which takes care of all of that. You just call it with the amount of memory you want to add, and `FstrBuf_Grow` will take care that the capacity matches the requirements by reallocing when necessary and at least as much as necessary.

```
...

void FstrBuf_Grow(FstringBuf *buf, size_t more)
{
    while (buf->length + more) > buf->capacity
        buf->capacity = 3 * buf->capacity / 2;
    buf->data = realloc(buf->data, buf->capacity + 1);
}
```

That multiplies `capacity` by 1.5 until `data` is large enough. You can choose different strategies, depending on your needs.

Comment: While your solution is a good one, the function `FstrBuf_Grow` will loop indefinitely...

Comment: @hiobs: Why should it loop indefinitely? I can think of some scenarios when `more` is huge, but I'd like to know which one you meant.

Comment: @hiobs: I use the same code in Delphi, but that does overflow and range checking, which C doesn't do. <g>

Comment: I think that's the problem, it can't be translated that easy from delphi to C :-) But as pointed out in the OP I've never done something like that in C either. If I have a choice, I'd always go with C++ instead. In my experience, C isn't great for string manipulation related stuff ...

Answer (score 1):

The `strncat(ptr->data, str, len);`, move before the `ptr->length = ((ptr->length) + len);` and use `strncpy(ptr->data+ptr->length...`. And the `ptr = NULL;` in the `Destroy` is useless.

The code of the "library" seems to be correct BUT be aware that you are continously reallocating the buffer. Normally you should try to grow the buffer only rarely (for example every time you need to grow the buffer you use max(2* the current size, 4) as the new size) because growing the buffer is O(n). The big memory allocation is probably because the first time you allocate a small buffer. Then you realloc it in a bigger buffer. Then you need to realloc it in a buffer even bigger and so the heap grows.

Comment: `Be aware that you are continously reallocating the buffer.` -- Are there alternatives for my approach?

Comment: @hiobs: Yes. The length becomes the length of the buffer (let's call it lengthbuffer). If you want you can even keep the length of the string (let's call it lengthstr) but it isn't necessary (you can always use strlen). lengthstr + 1 is always <= lengthbuffer. In the append, if lengthstr + len + 1 <= lengthbuffer then you can append without realloc (and you update only lengthstr += len), otherwise you realloc with new lengthbuffer = max(lengthbuffer * 2, 4).

Comment: I'll add that *2 and 4 are random numbers. In C# 2.0 the StringBuilder uses something like max(lenghtstr + len + 1, max(lengthbuffer * 2, 16))

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're re-allocating the buffer on every append. Shouldn't you grow it only when you want to append more than it can hold?

When reallocating you want to increase the size of the buffer using a strategy that gives you the best trade off between the number of allocations and the amount of memory allocated. Just doubling the size of the buffer every time you hit the limit might not be ideal for an embedded program.

Answer (score 0):

Generally for embedded applications it is much better to allocate a circular FIFO buffer 1-3 times the maximum message size.